# Google map grid only android

Tags: android, google-maps, apk

I tried to upload my apk to the android console, but it gives me the following message:

> You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign
>   your APK in release mode.

All I did was: I took the .apk from lib directory and then I zipalign it using command line as well.

After the failure of this, I tried other attitude as following:

(on the eclipse)Android tools --> export signed application project --> then I did all need to complete the creation of the new .apk.

And then I tried to upload the .apk again and I got everything just fine, but most of my app is based on a GoogleMapView and the MapView looks grid only... the weired thing is that If I try to send the apk just like that from the lib directory, to my e-mail, it goes just fine and show map as well... so the problem is not with the map key which is just fine.

I really tried everything, but it just seems to be not working, what should be the issue ?

Anyway, here's the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.moshe.wakoslakos"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.6" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/maps_key"/>

        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" 
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

I'm really desperate, please help me solve this issue... thanks :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the map key.

When you did `Android tools --> export signed application project -->`, your apk was signed with a new keystore. To get the maps to work with this, you'll have to get the MD5 hash of the keystore like you did for the debug.keystore, and generate a new API key. Then you use that API key and sign your apk again after building it.

Comment: can you explain it to me step by step ? because I didn't understood the steps as well... also why should I use another key ? if the MapView shows fine offline (eclipse) why it doesn't online (Play store) ?

Comment: @Adam Because the debug key used by Eclipse is not valid for production apps. It only lasts a year. Due to that, you need to use your own key. The process to get the MD5 is described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey)

Comment: But I created the current key less than a year ago... So every time you upload a MapView application, you have to create a new key ?

Comment: @Adam No. You use one key, which is not the debug key, for the rest of your app's life. When debugging, you use the debug key's API key. When you publish, you just change the API key in your project to the one corresponding to your production keystore. That's it

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I tried to create a product key from my debug MD5, and I couldn't find where I'm exactly doing this...